# How to change the default options for useQuery in react-query?

Tags: react-query

I feel there are hints in the documentation about setting the default options for `useQuery`, but I cannot figure out exactly how. For example, the QueryClient takes a `defaultOptions` constructor but then it's not clear how to attach that to `useQuery`. Maybe it is not possible?

Comment: Do you want to change these options for specific queries or just all queries in general?

Comment: yeah I wish to change the global default behaviour of useQuery

Comment: Then doing so in the `queryClient`'s `defaultOptions` is the way to go. These defaults will be used by all queries using that particular query client.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`defaultOptions` on the `QueryClient` will be applied to all queries, unless they have been specifically overwritten:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: { queries: { staleTime: 5000 } },
})
```

if you want to set defaults for specific queries, you can do that with:

```
queryClient.setQueryDefaults(['todos'], { staleTime: 3000 })
```